# How to replace blank values with null in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am working with tableau which is connected to `database`. The one `column` in it is `date information` which is in `sting format has missing values` hence it is very difficult to convert it to `DATE type`. Is there any way I can convert blanks with null or 0s? Following code did not work.

[image]

Comment: Personally, I think that there is nothing completely faster than your approach. Maybe a better solution could be to use a custom SQL statement from which the column arrives as DATE or NULL, not blank. See https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/customsql.htm

Comment: But my solution does not work, it is invalid calculated field. Error is can not compare date with string values.

Comment: What does the error message "say* if you click on the red triangle at the bottom of the calc editor? What is the data type of Return Date? Are you trying to compare a string '' or ' ' to something that is not of type string?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to "Data Source" tab you can set the column type as `Date` and everything that is not a date should be set to NULL.

For example, if you import this CSV

```
"C1";"C2";
"31/01/2021";"A";
"24/12/2001";"B";
" ";"C";
"";"D";
"1/1/2001";"E";
```

And you set `Date` on column `C1` as in the following image.

[image: screen 1]

alla blank values should be set to NULL.

[image: screen 2]